# QGIS Composer Legend not showing all map items

Tags: qgis, legend

I have 4 focus areas on a map... They are categorized by name, but the symbology is the same for all 4. When I add them to the print composer only the first 3 focus areas show up in the legend...

I'd like all 4 to be there as I want to have the focus areas named in the legend.

See attached screenshot.

[image: QGIS Legend Issue]

Answer (score 1):

Do you have the 'Filter Legend By Map Content' turned on - this would filter out the subareas in your legend if they are not in the view of your map. If not, try clicking the update all  button in the legend properties.

Personally if you are going to symbolise each area the same I would just have them symbolised as a single symbol rather than categorical. Then label the subareas appropriately in the map itself. As they are currently, the reader cannot derive any meaning from those categories when reading the map.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like it was an error to do with the name in the attribute data. I had labeled the areas on the map using the label tool in QGIS. I had the 'wrap text on character' selected and added a '+' as my break character using '+'. I then edited the name in the attribute table by adding a '+' between the 2-part name.

This wasn't an issue for 3 other layers in which I did the same thing. I erased the '+' from the name it seemed to solve the issue. I just labeled each area manually in composer.

I don't know if this is a bug or just something I missed when editing the name in the attribute table.

Thanks for the tips...

Answer (score 0):

I think I was having a very similar issue that caused the same problem, so this may help others. In my case the issue was a result of having more than one map in the Layout and the Legend not referring to the correct Map that had newly added active layers. To avoid this, in the Layout select the Legend and go Legend>Main Properties>Map and change the dropdown to the most recently added Map.